# How to set up PS3 Media Server to stream AceStream to PlayStation?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, streaming, ps3, ps3-media-server

I've been hunting around in net for weeks and trying no end of different setups and I feel like I’m going in circles.

I want to watch some live streams from AceStream on my PlayStation 3. I have installed [PS3 Media Server](https://github.com/ps3mediaserver/ps3mediaserver) and have installed Ace Stream Media 2.2.4. 
I also have VLC Player installed because some people said that is needed.

I have already configured PS3 Media Server to share the media on my Windows 7 computer, so I just need to get the live web streaming figured out now.

Unfortunately, I've not found any guides or information that seem to work with the existing version of PS3 Media Server.

I imagine that there are some Super User users that have set this up without any problem and hopefully can give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

After you have succesfully installed PS3 Media Server and enabled Sopcast Streaming (see other guide),
you can stream video and audio from Torrent Stream (Ace Stream).

Just follow the below steps:

1. Open TS Player (that’s Torrent Stream) and go to “Tools” → “Preferences”.
2. Click at the “All” radio button in the bottom “Show Settings” dialogue in order to display all the options.
3. Click “Stream Output” in the menu above.
4. In the Default Stream Output Chain, add the next line of code/string:

   ```
   #duplicate{dst="http{mux=ts,dst=:8902/tv.asf}",dst=display}
   ```
5. Check “Display While Streaming”.

6. Open Command Prompt (type `cmd` in the Windows search bar) and type `ipconfig` in order to discover your computer's internal IP address (it’s usually besides the IPv4 address).
7. Go to the `WEB.conf` file (for those of you who don't know, it’s under `C:/ProgramData/PMS` —it’s a hidden folder) and add the channel to PS3 Media Server by adding this line of code (open with WordPad):

   ```
   # TorrentStream
   videostream.Web,TorrentStream=TorrentStream,http://YOUR_INTERNAL_IP:8902/tv.asf,http://i.imgur.com/KXcQ6.jpg
   ```

   Replace YOUR_INTERNAL_IP with the IP address you got from step 6.

Your internal IP address may change from time to time;
check that they match each time.
Of course the Torrent Stream program & PS3 Media Server program have to work properly in order for PlayStation to stream!

Comment: Your answer (`WEB.conf`, step 7) contains an imgur URL that doesn’t make sense as part of an answer. Please [edit] and fix it.